# How to reload a dynamically loaded ES6 module (using import() as a function) without reloading the whole page?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cache-control, es6-modules

The following code will always log the same message even if the module has changed on the server, regardless of Cache-Control headers sent:

```
import('http://example.com/script.mjs').then(m => console.log(m.default))
```

unless the whole page is reloaded.
Is there a programmatic way to bust the dynamic import cache, similar to `delete require.cache[...]` in NodeJS?

Comment: Do you call `import` once? Normally when the module gets updated you should execute `import('http://example.com/script.mjs')` again.

Comment: Calling it again does not reload the module unless the whole page is refreshed. Try it in devtools. It makes sense usually since modules may have global singletons the rest of your code might rely on: same behavior as Node's require. However in Node you can manually bust it if you want.

Comment: Modules are cached by URL and I don't _think_ there isn't currently a way to invalidate that cache. Would it be feasible to have a random querystring on your script when loading dynamically?

Comment: That's indeed the only solution I found so far, but it also prevents the server from sending 304s when the script has actually *not* changed

Answer (score 0):

To avoid browser cache you should make script url dynamic.
There will be some overhead to get dynamic part of url (hash or query) from server.
But you will have wanted behaviour, no page reload and script refetch.

The advanced approarch is hot-module-replacement (`HMR`), for example in webpack https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/.

But webpack `HMR` is not for production usage, only for dev purpose.